# Unable to mock a hook in react, with react-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-testing-library

Summary of the issue: I have a test using a component, but inside this component theres a hook, that is returning a false value in the test, and i want to force that hook to be true. I attempted it in the code below, but it still always returns false

So i have the following test

```
 it("when click on save and form is correct calls CatalogService.updateCatalog", async () => {
    const emptyCatalog: API.Catalog = null;
    
    jest.mock("hooks/auth/AuthHooks", () => ({
      usePermissions: mockUsePermission,
    }));
    mockUsePermission.mockReturnValue([true, true]); 

    const onUpdateCatalog = jest.fn();

    render(
      <CreateCatalog
        onUpdateCatalog={catalog => onUpdateCatalog(catalog)}
        {...emptyCatalog}
      />
    );

    fireEvent.change(screen.getByRole("textbox", { name: /name/i }), {
      target: { value: "test" }
    });

    fireEvent.change(screen.getByRole("textbox", { name: /description/i }), {
      target: { value: "description" }
    });

    const saveButton = screen.getByTestId("save-button").closest("button");

    expect(saveButton.disabled).toBeFalsy();
    fireEvent.click(saveButton);
    await waitFor(() => CatalogService.updateCatalog);
    expect(
      CatalogService.createCatalog as jest.MockedFunction<
        typeof CatalogService.createCatalog
      >
    ).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

And this is the content at the top of the testing file, before the describe and all that

```
import { CreateCatalog } from "../CreateCatalog";
import { render, fireEvent, screen, waitFor } from "test-utils";
import CatalogService from "services/catalogs";
import { createMockCatalog } from "test-utils/mocks/Catalog.mock";

const mockUsePermission = jest.fn((...permissionCodes) => {
  return permissionCodes.map(() => true);
});

jest.spyOn(CatalogService, "createCatalog").mockImplementation(jest.fn());
jest.spyOn(CatalogService, "updateCatalog").mockReturnValue(
  Promise.resolve({
    data: {} as API.Catalog,
    status: 200,
    statusText: "200",
    headers: null,
    config: null
  })
);
const onUpdateCatalog = jest.fn();
```

SO as you can see, im trying to mock mockUsePermission to return always [true...]

and then inside the it (test) , i use it as follows

```
mockUsePermission.mockReturnValue([true, true]);
```

THe problem is that in the console.log that i put inside of createCatalog, i left this:

```
export const CreateCatalog: React.FC<API.Catalog & {
  onUpdateCatalog: (c: API.Catalog) => void;
}> = ({ onUpdateCatalog, ...catalog }) => {
  const {
    name,
    setName,
    description,
    setDescription,
    status,
    setStatus,
    statusOptions
  } = useCatalogForm(catalog);
  const [canCreate, canEditPermission] = usePermissions(
    Catalog.create,
    Catalog.details_edit
  );
  const isSaveDisabled =
    (!canEditPermission && !!catalog.id) || (!catalog.id && !canCreate);

  console.log(canCreate, canEditPermission)
  return (
    <Create
      disableSave={isSaveDisabled}
      successMessage={
        catalog
          ? "Catalog successfully updated!"
          : "Catalog successfully created!"
      }
    ......
```

and this console.log during the running of the test suite is always returning

```
false, false
```

THis is the original usePermission implementation

```
export const usePermissions = (...permissionCodes: Permission[]): boolean[] => {
  return AuthService.checkPermissions(permissionCodes);
};
```

Comment: why not just mock the AuthService? i dont think its the ideal for u mock the hook, we should just mock the service methods instead (not sure if mocking hooks is practically possible, in my pov we should just mock the service methods to test the integration )

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this

I put this in the top of the file

```
//we assume the user has permissions to create and edit catalogs
jest.mock("hooks/auth/AuthHooks", () =>
({
  usePermissions: () => [true, true]
}))
```

So now every hook will return [true,true] as i specify, but there was a specific test where i wanted it to be false so i did as follows

```
  it("if the user has no permissions to create a catalog, the save button is disabled", async () => {
    const usePermissions = jest.spyOn(require("hooks/auth/AuthHooks"), "usePermissions");
    usePermissions.mockReturnValue([false, false]); 
    const catalog: API.Catalog = createMockCatalog();
    render(<CreateCatalog onUpdateCatalog={onUpdateCatalog} {...catalog} />);

    const saveButton = screen.getByTestId("save-button").closest("button");
    expect(saveButton.disabled).toBeTruthy();
  });
```